# Why do `groups` and `groups $USER` give different results?

Tags: linux, user-groups

I want to add myself to the "docker" group. These are the commands I ran, and their output:

```
user1@laptop-p3510:~$ sudo usermod -a -G docker user1
user1@laptop-p3510:~$ groups
user1 adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare
user1@laptop-p3510:~$ whoami
user1
user1@laptop-p3510:~$ groups user1
user1 : user1 adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare docker
```

Am I in the "docker" group or not? Why does `groups $USER` give different results than `groups`?

Comment: Try re-logging in before running `groups` without parameters.

Comment: If you don't want to re-login you can do `newgrp docker` after adding you to the `docker` group and you will be able ot run `docker` without `sudo` without having to reopen the terminal/relogin

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Because you need to log out and back in again for the added groups to be active.

`groups` returns the groups you are a member of for the current session

`groups user1` checks to see what the config says that user is a member of.

Because you added `user1` to a group and you have not yet logged out and back in again, the groups `user1` was a member of when you logged in are the ones that current session will use.

Hope that helps

Comment: Yes, this was it. Thank you! I felt like I was in the Spongebob "that's not my wallet" meme.

Comment: Possibly also worth mentioning: `newgrp` can be used to start a new session without logging out and back in (but of course only the terminal you run it in will be using that new session).

Answer (score 11):

Like the UID and GID, groups are a *per-process* credential. Each process has its own list of groups that it belongs to, which is initialized from /etc/group at login time (by the initial process that handles your login) but inherited from the parent process otherwise.

So when you run `groups` from a shell, it inherits the group list from the shell (which has inherited them from the terminal app, etc) and that's the list it shows. The same applies to the UID and GID shown by `id` (and in fact also to environment variables shown by `env`). This list does not automatically change when /etc/group is updated – until the next time you log in.

Running `groups SomeUser` or `id SomeUser`, on the other hand, asks the program to read group information directly from /etc/group (in the same way that a login process would), so naturally it'll give you the updated list.

(User-switching tools like `su` and `sudo` also do the same, so if you urgently need to do something with a specific group you can "su" to root and then "su" back to yourself – su will reinitialize the group list as part of its job. You'll also notice that only the shell run by "su" has the new groups, while all other shells still show the old ones.)

To answer the question, yes, your *account* is in the "docker" group, but the specific shell you're running 'groups' from is not. Most things don't care about the account but only about the specific process that's performing the action (with some exceptions).